# In a manuscript, is an incomplete beta function a useful simplification of a sum, if the argument ends up negative?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, beta-distribution

I'm working on a manuscript which I intend to submit to a statistics journal. I have a sum which I "simplify" to the [regularized incomplete beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedBetaFunction.html) $I_{-t}(a,b)$, where $t$ is a positive real number, and $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

What I am worried about is that people may not be used to seeing this function with a negative argument, and will not be sure how it behaves or what its properties are. If it just ends up confusing people, then there is no point to this "simplification".

I don't think I can transform it to have the argument between 0 and 1. I mean, I can, using this [reflection formula](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.19.17.0008.01), followed by [this identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.19.17.0009.01). But then I have something involving $B_{\frac{1}{1+t}}(c, d)$ where $c$ and $d$ are *negative* integers, and strictly speaking the result is not even defined, and we must take a limit as $c$ and $d$ approach negative integers. So transforming the argument to be in $[0,1]$ seems to make the result even more confusing.

So, my question is, is $I_{-t}(a,b)$ acceptable as a "simplification" in a manuscript, or is it better just to write the sum I got it from? I realize this is a somewhat subjective question, so I'll probably just accept an answer pretty quickly.

Comment: Why not express it [in terms of hypergeometric functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) if you want to clarify your result?

Comment: I thought that readers would be familiar with the incomplete beta function, because it appears in the CDF of the binomial, negative binomial, and beta distributions; whereas if I write $_2 F _1$ it will look rather mysterious and send most of the readers to Google trying to figure out what it is. If writing results in terms of hypergeometric functions is more common than I thought, though, then maybe this would be a better option for communicating the formula.